# What accounts for the difference in factor of 4 between quantum cross section and classical cross section?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

In classical mechanics, we could calculate the total cross section of scattering from hard sphere to be $$\pi a^2$$
where $a$ is the radius of sphere.

Recently in quantum mechanics we calculated the scattering of $s$-wave from a hard sphere

The total cross section is calculated to be $$4\pi a^2.$$

**Is there a physical reasoning on why this two differ by a factor of 4?**

Comment: What about the two different calculations does not qualify as "physical reasoning"?

Answer (score -1):

In this [reference](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ebds10/aqp/lec20-21_compressed.pdf) the calculation leads to the factor of four , and it is attributed to the hard sphere  potential used in the calculation:

> Factor of 4 enhancement over classical value,πR2, due to diffraction processes at sharp potential.

A consequence of the wave nature of the wavefunction, I guess.